# Error while connecting SQL Server Vnext

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-vnext

I am running SQL Server Vnext (2017) in docker on MAC. I am able to connect SQL Server using command line utility mssql but not able to connect using Visual Studio Code. Can anyone help?

> mssql: Failed to connect: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 8 - Protocol not supported)

This error is specific to SQL Server 2017 - Visual Studio Code

Comment: What connection string did you use? I suspect you *didn't* use TCP inside VS Code. TCP will be used by default if you specify an IP address, a fully qualified name or `localhost`.

Comment: I created connection based on connection profile, it asked sequence of steps and it did not prompted for "Protocol", I am still able to connect using terminal

Comment: How to see the "Connection String" ?

Comment: You *specify* the connection string in order to connect. What did you use for the *server name*?